# Searching for a tag across all Stack Exchange meta sites

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to find all questions tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) on the meta sites of [all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Is there a better way than searching manually on each individual site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Simplest Approach

Use Google-fu. Combine the `site` operator, `*` (wildcard) and your query.

```
site:meta.*.stackexchange.com <query>
```

For example, [`site:meta.*.stackexchange.com community-ads`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site%3Ameta.*.stackexchange.com+%5Bcommunity-ads%5D)

> [image]

#### Longer Accurate Approach

Use the filters feature on Stack Exchange main site.

> [image]

Which results in:

> [image]

Comment: AFAIK Google ignores symbols or treats them as spaces (so `[community-ads]` is presumably equivalent to `community ads`). If I search for that now, I get 0 results that are about that tag. [I posted an answer with a Google search which seems to work better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300064/206447).

Answer (score 7):

**If you're looking for sites where a tag appears** (as opposed to wanting to search the actual questions containing that tag):

Building on another answer, type this into Google:

```
site:*/tags/{tag you want}/info
```

This gives you a nice list of all the sites containing that tag, with each site appearing only once.

To include more sites, but duplicate results (and increase the chance of including non-SE sites), remove `/info`:

```
site:*/tags/{tag you want}
```

This could potentially include a few non-Stack Exchange sites and is not limited to Meta, but trying to narrow it down with something like the below doesn't work so well.

```
site:*.stackexchange.com/tags/{tag you want}/info
```

For Meta-only, you can consider simply adding "meta" to the search: (although that's not perfect)

```
site:*/tags/{tag you want}/info meta
```

You might want to include similar results that Google excludes by default (link optionally appearing at the bottom of the results or add `&filter=0` to the URL).

**Example:**

[image]

This might not find all sites, but it can be a good starting point to find a tag.

Comment: Strange that `site:*.stackexchange.com/tags/community-ads/info` returns only 1 result.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713566/search-for-questions-with-a-specific-tag-across-meta-sites?tagName=community-ads) returns all [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) questions on Stack Exchange, newest first.

The top results at the moment of editing (February 6th, 2021) were:

- [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/386) (Joomla)
- [Community Ads 2020](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4713) (Stack Overflow en español)
- [Community Ads 2020](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8338) (Stack Overflow em Português)

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to https://stackexchange.com/ and put the tag [community-ads] [into the search box](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-ads%5D). (Or some other tag which you are interested in.) However, this search does not have various ways of sorting the search results which can be used when searching on a specific site. There is also no possibility to restrict this to meta sites. (There are some tags which appear both on per-site-metas and on main sites.)

Still, if you're interested only in some questions, you might be able to restrict the search query by adding more keywords. For example, here is the [search for [community-ads] 2020](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+2020). Or you can restrict the dates when the posts when the posts where created - which might be useful if you're interested in the recent posts. This can be achieved [using the search modifier created](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+created%3A2020-01-01..).